# Setting up fake URLs locally that support subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, url, subdomain

I'm developing a Rails 3 app locally on my Mac. I want to test it locally with fake URLs that support subdomains, e.g. http://blah.example.com and http://blah2.example.com. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run from your favorite shell and terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add this in a new line:

```
127.0.0.1    *.example.com
```

Press Ctrl+X to save.

---

Make sure you do **NOT** delete the lines that are already there!

Comment: [ghost](https://github.com/bjeanes/ghost#readme) is a great gem for managing these local hostnames from the command line.

Comment: This is a forum for programmers. Everybody who reads this is smart enough to choose their own favorite editor. Don't you even think abouts starting an editor war on this forum!

Comment: [local-subdomain](https://github.com/manuelvanrijn/local-subdomain) is also an option